# parsing cookie which has no equal sign (=)

Tags: java, android, parsing, cookies

I am developing a client app. Most of the app works with **WebView**. It loads several pages from the web server.

After authorizing user, I'll get all cookies and save them locally. Then, I'll put those cookies to `webView` via `CookieManager`, `CookieSyncManager`. After user navigating a certain page, the server returns the same cookies but this time with *a new value* adding to it. From that time onwards, I need to be able get that part of the cookie and sync it.

Note that I mustn't get new cookie and replace it with previous one, but find what is new in the cookie and add it to our *current one*.

I saw cookie-parsing issues and solutions. But what the server is returning is not similar to those standard **value-pair** ones. Here is how the cookie looks like

```
PHPSESSID=27dd72de72e1643727c4ddb150b2f988; aes_session=a%3A12%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22aaaaaaaa%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22e116b84c302d763a4f759caa5d178455%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22bbbbbbb%22%3Bs%3A15%3A%22111.111.111.111%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A40%3A%22Apache-HttpClient%2FUNAVAILABLE+%28java+1.4%29%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22jjjjjjjj%22%3Bi%3A1372138481%3Bs%3A9%3A%22cccccc%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22fail%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22ddddddd%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2231%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22eeeeee%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22ffffffff%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22ggggggg%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22hhhhhh%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A6%3A%22iiiiii%22%3Bs%3A1%3A
```

`iiiiii` and its following value is added in this example.

The question is, are there any parsers to deal with this kind of cookie or do I have to think of writing some regEx? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spec ([RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1)) says that cookies are name-value pairs.  According to the syntax in the RFC, the equals sign ('=') is mandatory.

It is therefore moot whether implementations will cope with missing equals sign characters.  A cookie without the equals sign is INVALID.  Your application ... or whatever it is that is setting those cookies ... is broken and should be fixed.

---

FWIW, if you want to specify a name/value pair with an empty value, it is legal to have nothing between the equal ('=') and the semicolon (';') or the end of the cookie string.  But the spec says that the '=' is mandatory.

---

(However, the thing that puzzles me about this Question is that the example cookie doesn't appear to have an example of a missing '=' ...)